# how to use org to open w3m url in a new window

Tags: org-mode, w3m

I often use `C-c l` key strike to store link in w3m
and use `C-c C-l` to save link in org

but when I click this link, the current org window jump to w3m window

I need the current org window not change
and open the link to w3m window in a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the behaviour you want by setting the `w3m-pop-up-windows` variable to `t`.  There's also `w3m-pop-up-frames` in case you want OS windows rather than Emacs windows.  You may have to ensure that `w3m-use-tab` is set to `nil` as it didn't seem to work in the same way when I had it enabled.

One of Emacs' best features is that it is self-documenting, and
contains help commands that let you access the documentation for any
function or variable that is used by Eamcs.  In this case I just
used `C-h f` to lookup the documentation for the `browse-url` function
which is what Emacs uses for asking a browser to display a URL.  Right
at the bottom of this it mentions the `browse-url-new-window-flag`
which sounds like it does exactly what you want.  You can then either click
on the link to read about that variable.

A quick experiment showed that it does the right thing for graphical
browsers, it doesn't work with w3m.  I then did `C-h f w3m-browse-url`
to find the w3m specific documentation and it describes the
`w3m-pop-up-windows` and `w3m-pop-up-frames` variables which do work
as expected.

There are many more commands and key bindings for accessing Emacs'
help system which is described in the [help section of the Emacs
manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Help.html#Help).
FWIW I also find these functions greatly enhanced when using an
incremental completion framework such as Ido (which comes with with
Emacs), [Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) (my personal choice), or [Helm](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/) (which do not).

Comment: very nice! how to find this solution?

Comment: Have extended the answer with some details on ways to access Emacs' documentation.